# Complex analysis: Radius of convergence of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos n \theta}{(\sqrt{13})^{n+1}}x^n
$$

Find the radius of convergence for the above series. I have learnt to use the root test and ratio test but neither of them seem to work. I have problems manipulating.

Not sure if this is useful: $\cos z = \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz} \right)$

Comment: I would use the fact that cosine is bounded.

Comment: @echoone what if $\theta$  is a complex number? In this case cosine is unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint.  For any $N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ we have that $\sup_{n>N}(\cos(n\theta))^{1/n} = 1$.  Now try the root test.

Comment: Is this correct if $\theta$ is a complex number? Isn't cosine of a complex argument unbounded by Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: @TheSubstitute yes.